# Kivy Add Widget Error

Tags: android, python, kivy

my problem is that when I want to run the example above, it will not work.
What happens is, the popup shows up once with the text "test" and then when I click the button again it shows the errors:

```
File "/home/river/android-sdk/workplace/python-forandroid/build/pythoninstall/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 76, in add_widget
File "/home/river/android-sdk/workplace/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 314, in add_widget
kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout object at 0x60a25a78>, it already has a parent <kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout object at 0x60e2bae8>
```

I think the reason being is that I have to remove the widget after each click.
(I dont know how to)

```
 import kivy
 import kivy.uix.label
 import kivy.app
 import kivy.lang.builder
 textshow = BoxLayout()
 def answer(answer):
      text = Label(text=str(answer))
      textshow.add_widget(text)
 Builder.load_string('''
 <main>:
     Button: 
         on_release: root.show()
 ''')
 class main(BoxLayout):
      def show(self):
           answer("test")
           popup = Popup(content=textshow)
           popup.open()
 class apprun(App):
     def build(self):
         return main()
 apprun().run()
```

If you answer this, please show whole code.

Edit: This is a sample script, my real script has 2 class Screen1, and
textshow = BoxLayout() class

Inclements answer worked, but every click of the button makes another textshow! Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple answer would be to store the popup and simply use the smae on each time. For instance, you could put `self.popup = Popup(content=textshow)` in your `build` method then change your `show` method to have `App.get_running_app().popup.open()`. This will always open the single saved popup, avoiding the problem.

Comment: Would this method still use the functions parameter (answer)? Or can you just show me the script with the improvisations?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work, but now, and this is hilarious, it is adding 1 more textshow each time the buttons clicked!